# How to download file in Spring mvc and mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

Hi have written controller class like below. I am trying to get file from mongo db and try to download it.

```
    organizationFileAttachmentService.setUser(getUser());
    GridFSDBFile file = organizationFileAttachmentService.getGridFSDBFileById(new ObjectId(id), "File");
    if (file != null) {
        byte[] content = organizationFileAttachmentService.findByIdAndBucket(new ObjectId(id), "File");
        try {
            int size = content.length;
            InputStream is = null;
            byte[] b = new byte[size];
            try {
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
                is.read(b);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (is != null)
                        is.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
            response.setContentType(file.getContentType());
            // String attachment =
            // "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFilename()+"\"";
            String attachment = "attachment; filename=" + file.getFilename();
            // response.setContentLength(new
            // Long(file.getLength()).intValue());
            response.setCharacterEncoding(file.getMD5());
            response.setHeader("content-Disposition", attachment);// "attachment;filename=test.xls"
            // copy it to response's OutputStream
            // FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            _logger.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '" + id + "'");
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }
```

but i am not able to down load file. can any one help me.

Comment: The line `response.setCharacterEncoding(file.getMD5());` is incorrecr. CharacterEncoding have to be "UTF-8" or some like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my request as GET and added request in anchor tag in html. Aslo changed my code as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFileById/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
void download(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    organizationFileAttachmentService.setUser(getUser());
    GridFSDBFile file = organizationFileAttachmentService.getGridFSDBFileById(new ObjectId(id), "File");
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            response.setContentType(file.getContentType());
            response.setContentLength((new Long(file.getLength()).intValue()));
            response.setHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getFilename());// "attachment;filename=test.xls"
            // copy it to response's OutputStream
            IOUtils.copyLarge(file.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            _logger.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '" + id + "'");
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }
    }
}
```

Now it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

In case you missed it, Spring provides various built in resource handlers.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations

If your method returns one of those (perhaps the ByteArrayResource in your case), then you just need a couple of annotations on the interface like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar/{fileId}", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
@ResponseBody FileSystemResource downloadFile(Long fileId);
```

No fiddling with encodings and headers for you that way. I'd recommend trying that before rolling your own.

Edit: The above worked fine in Spring 3.1.4. It no longer works for 3.2.x or 4.x. Whereas previously, the produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE } would cause Spring to add the appropriate headers, it now treats that as a restriction. If accessing the URL with a standard web browser, an accept header of "application/octet-stream" will not be sent. Spring will therefore return a 406 error. To get it working again, such a method needs to be re-written without the "produces" attribute. Instead, add HttpServletResponse to the method arguments and add the header inside the method. i.e.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar/{fileId}", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody FileSystemResource downloadFile(
            Long fileId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
    response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName );
    ...
}
```

Edit redux:
Now using Spring 4.0.7 via Spring Boot 1.1.8. It would appear that setting the `produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE }` instruction is now working again. Just having that instruction seems to be enough for all the browsers I have tried. Note however, that I have also found that it does not set the `Content-Disposition`, which is left as `application/json`. Although this doesn't seem to be an issue for browsers, I have come across bugs in PHP client applications, which seem to behave only based on the `Content-Disposition`. So it seems that the current solution is to do both of the above!